# What's the recommended way to copy multiple dotfiles with yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am building a yeoman generator for a fairly typical node app:

```
/
|--package.json
|--.gitignore
|--.travis.yml
|--README.md
|--app/
    |--index.js
    |--models
    |--views
    |--controllers
```

In the templates folder of my yeoman generator, I have to rename the dotfiles (and the package.json) to prevent them from being processed as part of the generator:

```
templates/
 |--_package.json
 |--_gitignore
 |--_travis.yml
 |--README.md
 |--app/
     |--index.js
     |--models
     |--views
     |--controllers
```

I see a lot of generators that copy dotfiles individually manually:

```
this.copy('_package.json', 'package.json')
this.copy('_gitignore', '.gitignore')
this.copy('_gitattributes', '.gitattributes')
```

I think it's a pain to manually change my generator code when I add new template files. I would like to automatically copy all files in the /templates folder, and rename the ones that are prefixed with _.

What's the best way to do this?

If I were to describe my intention in imaginary regex, this is what it would look like:

```
this.copy(/^_(.*)/, '.$1')
ths.copy(/^[^_]/)
```

**EDIT**
This is the best I can manage:

```
this.expandFiles('**', { cwd: this.sourceRoot() }).map(function() {
    this.copy file, file.replace(/^_/, '.')
}, this);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found this question through Google as I was looking for the solution, and then I figured it out myself.

Using the new `fs` API, you can use globs!

```js
// Copy all non-dotfiles
this.fs.copy(
  this.templatePath('static/**/*'),
  this.destinationRoot()
);

// Copy all dotfiles
this.fs.copy(
  this.templatePath('static/.*'),
  this.destinationRoot()
);
```

Comment: Also, worth noting that if you're using a glod in from the destination needs to be a directory.

Comment: This was the right answer, and deserves to be upvoted.  See my latest commit for a usage example: https://github.com/srsgores/generator-stylus-boilerplate/commit/d785cfe31e3a519edb3b75edb22a5dbc776ecdfd

Comment: Thanks! Also, this.destinationRoot() can be replaced with this.destinationPath("path/to/folder") for relative destinations (as indicated in srsgores' commit example).

Comment: If you have nested dot files as well, then you can use:
    `this.templatePath('static/**/.*')`

Comment: I'm sorry but why so much code? The answer below is better.

Answer (score 31):

Adding to @callumacrae 's answer: you can also define `dot: true` in the `globOptions` of `copy()`. That way a `/**` glob will *include* dotfiles. Example:

```js
this.fs.copy(
  this.templatePath('files/**'),
  this.destinationPath('client'),
  { globOptions: { dot: true } }
);
```

A list of available Glob options can be found in the [README](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) of `node-glob`.

Comment: Yeoman documentation is really bad. Where did you found the "globOptions" information? I know the list of options, however there is no hint about the base object name "globOptions".

Comment: @julmot I _think_ I've eventually found it following the **File Utilities** section on the [File System Docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html). They link to the `mem-fs-editor` npm package which provides the underlying implementation for the file system operations. In that README there are several mentions of `globOptions` (which then again lead to the `node-glob` package :-), which is also linked from the [API Docs for `actions/file`](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_file.html))

Comment: I was also struggling to handle the dot file but with fs.copyTpl which internally use fs.copy. But apparently fs.copyTpl dosen't accept globOptions like copy do. To overcome this situation here is a solution : this.fs.copyTpl(glob.sync('files/**', {dot: true}), 'client', context).

Comment: Erratum - the whole template path must be specified: this.fs.copyTpl(glob.sync(this.templatePath('files/**'), {dot: true}), 'client', context)

Comment: @NicolasForney For `copyTpl` it seems the `{globOptions}` needs to be in **5th** argument position ([eg. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083777/1266650)), as the [syntax](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copytplfrom-to-context-templateoptions--copyoptions) says `#copyTpl(from, to, context[, templateOptions [, ` **`copyOptions`** `]])`.

Comment: I don't know why, but this only seems to be working for me if the globOptions are in the 4th argument of copyTpl().

Answer (score 23):

Just got this working for me: the globOptions needs to be in the **fifth** argument:

```js
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath('sometemplate/**/*'),
  this.destinationPath(this.destinationRoot()),
  null,
  null,
  { globOptions: { dot: true } }
);
```

Comment: explain the downvote?  This is the current working version.

Comment: This is better. Prefer this.

Comment: For `copyTpl` you need to use the `fifth` argument with `globOptions` - I just updated the answer

Comment: This should be accepted. Works for me and the accepted one does not. Plus it's in the mem-fs docs

Comment: Preferable because it changes the behavior of the `copyTpl` function through an explicit option, instead of obfuscating the problem with multiple copy statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use templates that starts with a dot, you can use the `dive` module to achieve something identical:

```js
var templatePath = this.templatePath('static-dotfiles');
var destinationRoot = this.destinationRoot();
dive(templatePath, {all: true}, function (err, file, stat) {
    if (err) throw err;
    this.fs.copy(
            file,
            (destinationRoot + path.sep + path.relative(templatePath, file))
                    .replace(path.sep + '_', path.sep + '.')
    );
}.bind(this));
```

where `static-dotfiles` is the name of your template folder for dotfiles where `_` replaces `.` in filenames (ex: `_gitignore`).

Don't forget to add a requirement to `dive` at the top of your generator with

```
var dive = require('dive');
```

Of course, this also works for `copyTpl`.

Note that all subparts of paths that starts with a `_` will be replaced by a `.` (ex: `static-dotfiles/_config/_gitignore` will be generated as `.config/.gitignore`)