# How to ignore files in Yeoman with fs.copyTpl

Tags: json, yeoman, yeoman-generator

how can i ignore files? i want to exclude all file starting with _ in any subdirectory. i have no success with these two approaches:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
   this.templatePath('basicFiles/'),
   this.destinationPath(''),
   answers,
   {ignore:"_*.*"}
);

this.fs.copyTpl(
  [!*.*,this.templatePath('basicFiles/')],
  this.destinationPath(''),
  answers
);
```

More general, would like to merge(deep copy) every basic/_exmaple.json into additionalConfig/example.json to desitnationPaht/exmaple.json (merged).

Every idea is welcome :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `fs.copyTpl` your `{ignore:"_*.*"}` needs to be in the **5th** argument object (as the [syntax](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copytplfrom-to-context-templateoptions--copyoptions) says) and inside **`globOptions`** key:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath('**/*'), // from
  this.destinationRoot(),    // to
  {},  // context            // not here
  {},  // templateOptions    // not here
  { globOptions: {ignore:"_*.*"} } // < but here
)
```

Same for `{dot: true}` and other such options.

Comment: That is awesome.

Comment: You now need to give an array for ignore : ```{ globOptions: {ignore: ["_*.*"]} } ```